# UILocalNotification end date

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I wonder if it's possible to set end date for `UILocalNotification`?

I want my notification to fire everyday (`NSDayCalendarUnit`) but I have end date which I cannot cross (deadline) e.g. I'm taking a photo of my growing mustache everyday for one year period and after a year notifications won't be displayed.

I hope you got my point of view...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not such option in [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as you can read in the documentation.

Your only option is to check wether the year is over when every the user starts the app.

Comment: ...And after checking decide if the notification should be cancelled. This answer is not what I wanted to hear but now I'm sure I cannot acomplish this. Thanks @rckoenes

Answer (score 1):

In the `UILocalNotification` object, I'd recommend setting the `repeatInterval` property and putting the end date in the `userInfo` dictionary for querying later to determine if the notification has expired. For example:

```
UILocalNotification* uiLocalNotification;
uiLocalNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 

//Set the repeat interval
uiLocalNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;

NSDate* fireDate = ...

//Set the fire date
uiLocalNotification.fireDate = fireDate;

//Set the end date
NSDate* endDate = ...

uiLocalNotification.userInfo = @{
                                  @"endDate": endDate
                                };

UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application scheduleLocalNotification:uiLocalNotification];

//...

//Somewhere else in your codebase, query for the expiration and cancel, if necessary

UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray* scheduledNotifications = application.scheduledLocalNotifications;

NSDate* today = [NSDate date];

for (UILocalNotification* notification in scheduledNotifications) {

    NSDate* endDate = notification.userInfo[@"endDate"];

    if ([today earlierDate:endDate] == endDate) {
        //Cancel the notification
        [application cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Use following code:

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

Comment: I know how to manage `repeatInterval` property and this is not what I was asking about.