# UILocalNotification with repeatInterval how to set finish date?

Tags: date, uilocalnotification

i have a UILocalNotification with repeatInterval set like this:

```
UILocalNotification *ln = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
ln.alertBody         = text;
ln.timeZone          = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
ln.fireDate          = [self dateFromString:atDate];
ln.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

I want to stop the repeat at specified date.

How can i do this?

Thanks, 
Simone

Comment: possible duplicate of [UILocalNotification end date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077791/uilocalnotification-end-date)

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer here: [UILocalNotification end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077791/uilocalnotification-end-date), there is no such property found in the documentation for UILocaNotification.